# How can I change my monster's name on Tiny Monsters?

Tags: tiny-monsters

This is a question that is really annoying me, I have not found the answer any where.

Here it is: Can you change a monster's name on Tiny Monsters, and if so HOW?

I am asking this because all of my fire monsters are called " Sunspot"

Answer (score 3):

To change the monsters name, touch the habitat, touch the monster, and then touch the name displayed on the upper left.  The keyboard will open, and you can change the name to anything you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I've been having the exact same problem, simply re-hatch all of your monsters until you find the right name. The game also picks any name at random so watch out.

Answer (score -1):

No, unfortunately. You can not change the name of your monsters.

Comment: This appears to no longer be correct.